# ITextsharp Html2Pdf CSS issue

Tags: html, css, itext

I am new to iTextSharp, currently working on conversion of HTML to PDF using Html2pdf (iTextSharp extension). I am able to generate pdf but not able to add logo to pdf on every page.

Image coming but I can't change width of images.

CSS what I am using for pdf logo is below:

```
@page { 
@top-left { 
content:"test "; 
background:url(../images/template/test_logo_pdf.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
border:1px solid red;
background-color: #cccccc;

margin-top:10px;
} 
@top-right { 
content: flow(header); 
}
@bottom-right { 
content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages); 
font: 8pt Arial, sans-serif; 
} 
@bottom-left { 
content: string(repname); 
font: 8pt Arial, sans-serif; 
}
}
```

Comment: XML Worker is an iTextSharp 5 extension; pdfHTML is an iText 7 for .NET extension. You talk about the Html2pdf iTextSharp extension. That's confusing, and since you only show HTML code and no iText code, it's impossible to know which version of iText you are using. Could you clarify?

Comment: Moreover: I don't think `background:url(../images/template/test_logo_pdf.jpg)` is currently supported in any version. It's something that is scheduled for one of the next releases. That doesn't mean you can't add a logo on every page. See https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml and search for **Adding a background and a custom header or footer**.

Comment: I am using itextsharp 7 . I will try your suggestion in second comment and will let you know . Thanks

Comment: Please allow me to clarify that there is no such thing as itextsharp 7. The name iTextSharp was abandoned when we moved from version 5 to 7. At the same time, the Stack Overflow tag itextsharp was removed as a duplicate of the tag iText. The new name is **iText for .NET**. Please use the correct name in order to avoid confustion.

Comment: Actually `background: url(...)` is supported in all versions of pdfHTML. What is not supported yet is `background-size` which is needed in this use case.

Comment: Hi bruno.. will you please help me to understand what is parameter stationery in function createPdf and how is this different from dest ?

Comment: hi Yulian is there any CSS what i can use in place of background-size ? which is supported

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed not entirely easy to control dimensions of images added to the page margin boxes. One possible approach that I can suggest is to add image as a content (rather than as background-image) and make use of custom tag worker, that would specify height and width as desired for page margin box children images:

HTML:

```
@top-left {  
  content: url(../images/template/test_logo_pdf.jpg);
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

This is Java code, however .NET version has exact same API, only differing in code style (captial letters in the beginning of method names, etc.):

```
private static class PageMarginBoxImagesTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (tag.name().equals(PageMarginBoxContextNode.PAGE_MARGIN_BOX_TAG)) {
            return new PageMarginBoxImagesWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return super.getCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
}

private static class PageMarginBoxImagesWorker extends PageMarginBoxWorker {
    public PageMarginBoxImagesWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean processTagChild(ITagWorker childTagWorker, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (childTagWorker.getElementResult() instanceof Image) {
            // Or set fixed dimensions via setWidth/setHeight
            ((Image) childTagWorker.getElementResult()).setAutoScale(true);
        }
        return super.processTagChild(childTagWorker, context);
    }
}
```

And make use of the PageMarginBoxImagesTagWorkerFactory by specifying it in `ConverterProperties`:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlSrc, pdfDocument, 
        new ConverterProperties()
                .setTagWorkerFactory(new PageMarginBoxImagesTagWorkerFactory()));
```

Comment: Glad to help @bikash ! If answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted.